# Lan connection off after upgrades

Tags: lan

My lan connection is not working after my ubuntu 14.04 asked for routine upgrades of software.
Kindly help

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail? What did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in you question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Workaround to enable cable DHCP conectivity**

To enable lan via DHCP you can try to modify interfaces file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then add next lines:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Save (ctrl+o), press enter and exit nano (ctrl+x). You can try to restart your network with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

But if it doesn't work, restart your computer.

Now you will be able to follow the steps provided in the post suggested by kos with a DHCP wired connection